# asp.net core razor pages project in visual code localhost:5001 return This site can’t be reached

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Windows Server 2012,
ASP.NET Core 3.0

I installed new application razor pages and try to run in debug mode in visual code
I open project on localhost:5001 but get error in browser:

> This site can’t be reached. The webpage at https://localhost:5001/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/WebApplication1.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Pages": "${workspaceFolder}/Pages"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Additional information**:

[image]

[image]

I tried to run project in visual studio. If I select run with IIS is everything fine, but if I use Project name is similar error.

Comment: 1. Did you see a message of `Now listening on: https://localhost:5001` on `DEBUG CONSOLE`? According to the configuration, when you press `F5`,  VSCode will build & run your project, after that it will launch a browser and navigate to the URI automatically. 2. What do you get if you run command `dotnet run --urls=https://localhost:5001`?

Comment: Yes, i see this. I updated question with this information. check please

Comment: Could you please also show us the logs when you accessing `https://localhost:5001`? Please change all the `LogLevel` in `appsettings.json` to `Debug`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have below entry in your startup file.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: No. I dont use mvc. I use just app razor pages.
My startup has 

`
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
`